# Turtle won't turn around after hitting a wall

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I made it so that the turtle draws a 200x200 box then bounce around inside it. But the problem is that it does not bounce off the top or left wall.

```
t = turtle.Turtle()
s = turtle.Screen()
t.speed(1)

for i in range(4):
    t.forward(200)
    t.left(90)

t.penup()
t.goto(4, 4)
t.seth(r.randint(1, 89))

while 200 > t.xcor() > 0 and 200 > t.ycor() > 0:
    if t.xcor() >= 197:
        t.right(200)
    if t.xcor() <= 3:
        t.seth(r.randint(t.heading(),180))
    if t.ycor() >= 197:
        t.seth(r.randint(t.heading(), 180))
    if t.ycor() <= 3:
        t.left(200)

    t.forward(1)
```

This code allows the turtle to bounce off the right wall and the bottom one. When it reaches the left or top wall, the turtle turns toward the left side of the screen and keeps moving off the screen. I tried random numbers for `setHeading()` and also tried using `left()` and `right()` to control what the turtle does when it hits a wall. What am I doing wrong here? Or what is a better method of having the turtle move away from the walls?

Explained differently: the turtle doesn't turn around when it hits left and top walls, why? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've solved your problem, let's fix your code.  When you write a loop like this:

```
while 200 > t.xcor() > 0 and 200 > t.ycor() > 0:
    if t.xcor() >= 195:
```

you're effectively creating an infinite loop as the inner logic prevents the `while` condition from ever being `False`.  It's as if you said `while True:`.  But you should never say `while True:` in an event-driven environment like turtle as you can block out other events and possibilities.

Let's rewrite your code to be completely event driven, and while we're at it, centered on the screen:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randint

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-100, -100)
turtle.pendown()

for _ in range(4):
    turtle.forward(200)
    turtle.left(90)

turtle.penup()
turtle.home()
turtle.setheading(randint(0, 360))

def move():
    if -90 < turtle.xcor() < 90 and -90 < turtle.ycor() < 90:
        pass  # I hate 'if's like this but it's simpler than the alternative
    else:
        turtle.setheading(turtle.heading() + 180 + randint(-45, 45))
        turtle.forward(1)  # extra bump forward to get out of trouble

    turtle.forward(1)
    screen.ontimer(move, 25)

move()
screen.mainloop()
```

Not perfect, but you can see it gets the motion you desire without locking out other things that you might want to happen (like keyboard events, closing the window via a click, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my numbers were a bit off, `seth()` or `setHeading()` can actually go up to 360. So when I did `random.randint(heading(), 180)` it probably couldn't find a value if `heading()` was greater than 180. These modifications solved my problem.

```
if t.xcor() >= 195:
        t.seth(150)

    if t.xcor() <= 5:
        t.seth(r.randint(t.heading(),310))

    if t.ycor() >= 195:
        t.seth(r.randint(t.heading(), 300))

    if t.ycor() <= 5:
        t.left(150)
```